# Contentful error when using client.fetchArray

Tags: swift, contentful

I'm getting the following error when trying to follow [this](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/ios/tutorials/using-delivery-api-with-swift/) tutorial:

Oh no something went wrong: `A response for the QueryOn<Thing> did return successfully, but a serious error occurred when decoding the array of Thing.
Double check that you are passing Thing.self, and references to all other EntryDecodable classes into the Client initializer.`

when using the following code to call contentful:

```
func fetch() {
    let query = QueryOn<Thing>.where(field: .description, .exists(true))

    client.fetchArray(of: Thing.self, matching: query) { (result: Result<ArrayResponse<Thing>>) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let things):
            guard let firstThing = things.items.first else { return }
            print(firstThing)
        case .error(let error):
            print("Oh no something went wrong: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

My Thing model is set as so: [image]

and i currently have two `Things` added: [image]

My Thing class looks like so:

```
final class Thing: EntryDecodable, FieldKeysQueryable {

    enum FieldKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, description
    }

    static let contentTypeId: String = "thing"

    let id: String
    let localeCode: String?
    let updatedAt: Date?
    let createdAt: Date?

    let name: String
    let description: String

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let sys = try decoder.sys()

        id = sys.id
        localeCode = sys.locale
        updatedAt = sys.updatedAt
        createdAt = sys.createdAt

        let fields = try decoder.contentfulFieldsContainer(keyedBy: Thing.FieldKeys.self)

        self.name  = try! fields.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)!
        self.description = try! fields.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description)!
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what im missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so Contentful's documentation is all over the place. I had the same issue, but I managed to solve it after checking their documentation in their GitHub repo [itself](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.swift).

Basically you need to pass all Swift classes that conform the 'EntryDecodable' and 'FieldKeysQueryable' inside the Client initializer method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is amazing thank you! For anyone else reading this `contentTypeClasses` must be passed as shown in the Readme pointed out by @Gabriel Trujillo  here: https://github.com/contentful/contentful.swift#map-contentful-entries-to-swift-classes-via-entrydecodable

Comment: Thank you. I read it 5 times in the console but it managed to go around my head :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to make it easier for people visiting. All you need to do is ensure you've passed in your contentTypeClasses into the client Init method.

https://github.com/contentful/contentful.swift#map-contentful-entries-to-swift-classes-via-entrydecodable

```
fileprivate let client = Client(spaceId: spaceKey, accessToken: contentDeliveryKey, contentTypeClasses: [YourCustomClass.self])
```

```
final class YourCustomClass: EntryDecodable, FieldKeysQueryable {
    static let contentTypeId: ContentTypeId = "yourCustomContentfulType"

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let sys         = try decoder.sys()
        id              = sys.id
        localeCode      = sys.locale
        updatedAt       = sys.updatedAt
        createdAt       = sys.createdAt
}
```

Thanks @Wazza for sharing the link to contentful's github docs.